# How to enable Code coverage for pull requests capability for TypeScript and C#

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

is it possible to enable code coverage for pull requests capability for both TypeScript and C#?

I have a .NET Core web API program where the frontend is built using TypeScript, and the backend is built using C#, TypeScript and C# code in one project. In pipeline we use VSTest@2 to generate coverage reports for C# ,while for TypeScript, we use Jest. However, the Code coverage report tab can only display the coverage report of C#, I tried generating coverage reports in Cobertura format and using ReportGenerator to combine them in pipeline, which works for the coverage report tab but not in the pull request.

Is there a way to make this pull request check(below screenshot) support both TypeScript and C#?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GC8f9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your problem but I'm afraid it's not supported yet.

As per the doc [Code coverage for pull requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/codecoverage-for-pullrequests?view=azure-devops), the feature is available only for .NET and .NET core projects using the Visual Studio code coverage results format (file extension .coverage). Support for other languages and coverage formats will be added in future milestones.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, wade, if can't use the pull request check, is there a way to use Jest or other test framework to test TypesScript in pipeline? if the code coverage can't match the minimal percent , then fail the pipeline.

Comment: Yes, you can refer to the sample [link](https://thenikhilk.com/2020/09/18/publish-code-coverage-azure-pipelines-react/), need to parse the coverage and compare with minimal percent, and fail the pipeline if needed. It's recommended to raise a new ticket as it's a new query for the coverage check behavior.